# How to get an abstract dataclass to pass mypy?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses, abstract-base-class

*mypy* v0.910 rejects abstract dataclasses in Python 3.9. Here's the Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Liquid(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def drip(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Here's the error message:

```
$ mypy --python-version 3.9 so.py
so.py:4: error: Only concrete class can be given where "Type[Liquid]" is expected
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How do I get this code to pass *mypy*?

---

**Notes**

I gather from [mypy issue #5374](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5374) that this is a bug in *mypy*, first noticed in 2018 and still not corrected. I figure that people must be using *mypy* with abstract dataclasses, though, so there must be a workaround or a correct way to define or annotate the class. What is recommended?

The basis for the error message seems to be that *mypy* assumes that any object of type `Type` can be instantiated, but abstract classes cannot be instantiated. This appears to be the error since `Type` is [defined](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.Type) to mean a class object, not necessarily a concrete class object (i.e. one that can be instantiated).

Adding `# type: ignore` to the line containing `class Liquid` does not block the error message. Since the code does not contain `Type[Liquid]`, I figure it must be in the code generated by `dataclass`. `Type` is deprecated in Python 3.9, but apparently the `dataclass` code generator still generates it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of using the dataclass decorator here?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The purpose is only to make a Minimal Reproducible Example. The dataclasses in my production code have member attributes. I just double-checked, and the example does fail if I add a member attribute.

Answer (score 11):

Create a dataclass as a mixin and let the ABC inherit from it:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass    

@dataclass
class LiquidDataclassMixin:
    my_var: str

class Liquid(ABC, LiquidDataclassMixin):
    @abstractmethod
    def drip(self) -> None:
        pass
```

This works with mypy type checking as well. I recommend against using `# type: ignore` as that defeats the point of type-checking. Taken from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5374#issuecomment-568335302).

Comment: When I first saw this approach, I was worried that it would create clutter since each abstract dataclass needs a separate mix-in class. But I just went through my entire codebase and only found four abstract dataclasses, so this is definitely workable. Thanks!

Comment: I just unaccepted this answer because of a problem explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70999513/1393162). I would much prefer to keep type-checking on, so if you (or anyone) can tell me how to avoid that problem, I'll re-accept this answer. I also posted a solution there, with an explanation. Please take a look and see what you think.

Comment: Say, what is the reason for putting ABC ahead of LiquidDataclassMixin? This might be a crucial piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

Add `# type: ignore` to the decorator line. So in your case it would be:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass  # type: ignore[misc]
class Liquid(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def drip(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Comment: After a lot more coding and running into more problems, I've decided that turning off type-checking in the decorator line is indeed the correct solution, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70999704/1393162). If you change `type: ignore` to `type: ignore[misc]`, I'll accept this answer. (I'll edit it myself if I don't hear from you soon.)

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for the update, and sorry for such a late response :)

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the merge request ["Use a dedicated error code for abstract type object type error"](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/13785), we will soon be able to disable it globally either using `--disable-error-code=type-abstract` in the command line or adding `disable_error_code =type-abstract` to the configuration file. (Possibly from the coming `v0.983`)

For non-global use cases, it might be sufficient to add [`# type: ignore[type-abstract]`](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/docs/source/error_code_list.rst#safe-handling-of-abstract-type-object-types-type-abstract) at the end of the respective line.

Comment: Thanks! When v0.983 comes out, it looks like this will be the winning answer.

Comment: `v0.991` is out and has included the update for `type-abstract`.